# Style is not being applied to H1 element in CSS

Tags: html, css, html-heading

I'm facing a strange problem, the  style is not being applied to the `H1` element.

Code:

```css
p h1 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <h1>This is a header</h1>
</p>
```

Comment: You cannot put an H1 in a paragraph, it's not valid.

Comment: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/49449

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You **can't** have a heading (`H1` to `H6`) as a child of a `p`, **that's invalid HTML.**

It's not working because your browser is automatically closing the `p` element before the `h1` element starts, leaving you with this generated DOM (code) below:

```
<p> </p>
<h1>This is a header</h1>
<p> </p>
```

Using either the <kbd>F12</kbd> to acess your browser's developer tools or  using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> to view the source code, you can see this generated DOM above.

---

Instead, you can have a `span`  inside a `p` or a heading (`H1` to `H6`)

```css
h1 {
  color: red;
}
h2 span {
  color: green
}
p span {
  color: blue
}
```

```html
<h1>This is a header</h1>
<h2><span>This</span> is a second header</h2>
<p><span>This</span> is a paragragh</p>
```

See more about [headings contents](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#heading-content) and [phrasing elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/common-models.html#common.elem.phrasing) in the W3C Specification

Comment: You can have a `span` inside a `p` tag or any other [PhrasingElement](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/common-models.html#common.elem.phrasing)

Comment: On that note, the way to debug these sort of issues is to look at the **generated** DOM by browser using a browser inspector.

Comment: @dippas awesome, saved my day